# Window's glass - black stripes

Tags: materials, glass

Does anybody has an idea, why the black artefact is rendered as on attached screenshot?
Glass material is just assigned to two faces of the window.
[image: window]
[image: material]

Comment: what happens if you just use the Glass BSDF node, just for testing.

Comment: Might be something to do with your second mix shader node having nothing in the second input?

Comment: What did you expect from the second mix shader? A disconected socket means no shader (black), that is getting mixed with another shader using the camera ray (meaning "what the camera sees"). That translates into "this shader, when seen from the camera will be black"